# TSQL Repeat values on outer join

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've been working on this for some time now and I would like to get some help.

My database is SQL Server 2008 R2 ( I know, very old).

I basically have a transaction table that captures values per week, by job.

I would like to repeat the last value of a job until it finds the next value.

I have included some data from my table.  The last column (values needed) is what I'm trying to achieve.

Thank you very much.

Bruce

[image of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN4a1.png)

I've tried the SQL below, but it is not giving the correct values.  Please see the attachment.

SQL

```
 select t.*, t2.percentcomp as value_needed
```

from #1 t

```
 outer apply
 (select top 1 t2.*
  from #1 t2
  where t2.job_skey = t.job_skey and
        t2.COST_CODE_SKEY=t2.COST_CODE_SKEY and 
        t2.period_end_date <= t.period_end_date and
        t2.percentcomp is not null

  order by t.JOB_SKEY,t.phase,t.period_end_date desc
 ) t2
```

Attachment..[view of SQL.  Value_needed should begin with 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48bFY.png)

Comment: Edit your question and include sample data and desired results *in the question*.

Comment: do you mean to do this at the time of `INSERT`, so subsequent rows inherit the previous value of the same job if not specified, or default to 0; or are you after a `SELECT` statement that completes it on the fly?

Comment: hello, this is not an insert, but just a query to show the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want using `OUTER APPLY`:

```
select t.*, t2.percent_comp as value_needed
from t outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.job_skey = t.job_skey and
            t2.period_end_date_id <= t.period_end_date_id and
            t2.percentcomp is not null
      order by t2.period_start_date desc
     ) t2;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bzeq.png)

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the comment, but it is not giving the expected results.  The column value needed is not showing the first occurrence of PERCENTCOMP.

 I added an image to your comment where it says enter image description here.

Comment: @user3200403 . . . A closer inspection of your data reveals that `start_date` and `end_date` do not result in the same ordering.  I think you want the ordering by `start_date` rather than `end_date`.

Comment: I'm confused, there's no start date or end date.  One is a date and the other column just turns it into an integer.

Comment: @user3200403 . . . Oh, I see.  I think you need the `id` because it should be ordered correctly.

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  The issue is that it's the Value_Needed column is not picking up the new "PECENTCOMP" value when there is one.  It is just repeating the last value.

Comment: Hey Gordon, I got it!!!!  You were on the right track. I just needed to order by t2 instead of t. Here is your modified SQL.  Thanks so much!!



  
  select t.*, t2.percentcomp as value_needed
from #1 t
   
     outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from #1 t2
      where t2.job_skey = t.job_skey and
   t2.COST_CODE_SKEY=t.COST_CODE_SKEY and 
            t2.period_end_date_ID <= t.period_end_date_ID and
            t2.percentcomp is not null
           
      order by --t.JOB_SKEY,t.phase,
      t2.period_end_date_ID desc
     ) t2

Comment: @user3200403 . . . You are correct.  Almost everything in the subquery should be `t2`.  Typo on my part.  Sorry about that.